# Digitizing takes a long time

Tags: digitizing

While in the process of digitizing for instance a large body of water or piece of land it takes a long time to process. Is this normal? If not what can I do to speed up the process.

Comment: What software are you using ? What imagery are you using and tell us what were you trying to do ?

Comment: What source are you digitizing from? Is it automated feature extraction or manual creation (the phrase "long time to process" is kind of confusing)? Is there a target resolution or accuracy you're working from? Are you capturing more points than you really need to?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, manual digitization is slow.

There's a reason why scanning and raster-to-vector processing has replaced digitizing in major paper map conversion efforts.  Twenty-five years ago, half of Esri's employees toiled at 4-hour shifts on digitizer boards or worked at QC tasks reviewing data collection.  Now there may be a few large boards left, but they're likely sitting in closets, and there aren't any staffers with a job title of "Digitizer".

Very few of the ways of increasing speed of manual data capture result in improved data quality, and you probably don't want "extensive experience" (years) at a digitizer to earn that goal.

Comment: Last time I tablet digitised on an A0 (large) board was in 2006... raster to vector conversion is much faster.

Comment: That may work for paper maps, but it still has a long way to go for imagery last time I checked. Progress is being made for sure, but I spent most of 2010 and 2011 as a digitizer/QC working from sat imagery (eight hours a day). The company still does it, and there are others who do the same thing. I'm not sure what methods the companies doing plan/profile/alignment work around here on pipelines and such use. Almost nobody uses boards though, it's mostly  heads-up and has been for a while.

Comment: +1 for making me smile with this answer! I must admit that I had one of those 'In my day we spent the summer digitizing a map sheet and knew it was good for us' moments when I read the question. I'm still a fairly young man so I didn't think I'd find myself making these statements for quite some time. I guess it's the pace of progress!